# Move a SKSpriteNode with a single tap, but move continously when long tap - Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, sprite-kit

I'm trying to change some SKActions of an existing Sprite Kit tutorial project, but I'm running into issues when it comes to movement. The Tutorial and GitHub project is here:

https://www.codefellows.org/blogs/simple-sprite-kit-game-tutorial-part1

https://github.com/megharastogi/GameTutorial

As you can see in the code below, each tap only moves the node once. How do I change it so that a long tap will move continuous move the node? I tried a few things like repeatActionForever, but that didn't work very well.

```
-(void)addShip
{
        //initalizing spaceship node
        ship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        [ship setScale:0.5];
        ship.zRotation = - M_PI / 2;

        //Adding SpriteKit physicsBody for collision detection
        ship.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ship.size];
        ship.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = shipCategory;
        ship.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        ship.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = obstacleCategory;
        ship.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
        ship.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        ship.name = @"ship";
        ship.position = CGPointMake(120,160);
        actionMoveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:30 duration:.2];
        actionMoveDown = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-30 duration:.2];

        [self addChild:ship];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
    if(touchLocation.y >ship.position.y){
        if(ship.position.y < 270){
            [ship runAction:actionMoveUp];
        }
    }else{
        if(ship.position.y > 50){

            [ship runAction:actionMoveDown];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedScreen:)];
    tapper.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
}

- (void)tappedScreen:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    float touchY = [self convertPointFromView:[recognizer locationInView:self.view]].y;
    SKSpriteNode *ship = [self childNodeWithName:@"ship"];
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if(touchY >ship.position.y){
            [ship runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:actionMoveUp] withKey:@"longTap"];
        }else{
            [ship runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:actionMoveDown] withKey:@"longTap"];
        }
    }
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [ship removeActionForKey:@"longTap"];
    }
}
```

Add these two methods in your code.